# Cannot create a steam library on my 4tb hard drive as its read only

Tags: hard-drive

I recently downloaded the latest ubuntu which is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, i downloaded steam with the hopes of using my 4tb hdd to create a steam library in. However everytime i try i got the error that the drive needed to be made executable. after a few attempts at different methods on ask ubuntu forums(most of them where based on older ubuntus like 14.04 and non of the methods worked.

Could someone please give me a solution as i really need it

Comment: Your questions lacks a couple of things to have anyone be able to create an answer. Where did you intend to create the library? Do you own that location? Are you perhaps trying to put in on a partition that is mounted with a windows filesystem? what is the actual command you used? what is the actual error? cuz "a drive needs to be made executable" seems to me to be a wrongly mounted partition or lack of permission on the directory but ... all I can ask are questions and not an answer ;-) Please add information to the question where someone can make an answer on.

Comment: so the drive that cant be  written by steam is /media/terry/fbc1db60-b9d2-4ae8-9452-11a81648951d its just read only according to steam. i formated the harddrive to fat32 to see if that makes any difference which it didnt so i reformatted back to ntfs tried the cmod method as well as attempting to change usergroups but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: You should use a linux partition, like that of your system partition, not a windows file system(mdos or ntfs). Use GPart or disks to accomplish that...

Comment: fair enough, didnt realise how bad windows partitioning was until now

Comment: That's not te problem, if you use some *nix-bsd system you should use the native supported file systems no?

Comment: not sure if that would work but changing the hard drives partition from ntfs to ext then doing the chown command to make my user the owner of that partition seems to have done the trick, I'm just crap at using linux as i have just made the full switch from windows 10 to ubuntu on my gaming rig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to give next time some more info I think, but I'll try....

If external disk, search first if there's a little qwitch button or knob on the disk drive, and switch it to unlock if neccesary.

Else
See if the disk partitioned/formatted and how?
To see disk partitions do:

1. Open Disks.(program)
2. Find your drive.
3. See if it is partitioned and use one of them and see if it is formatted.
4. Find out the characteristics of the partitions.(little wheel under disk layout)
5. See if it is writable or read only(rw or ro)
6. Change the option if neccesary
7. Save changes and unmount disk.(upper right menu)
8. Remount disk in the left list....
   Should work... Use help menu if neccesary!

Comment: it was formatted as ntfs initially before trying fat32 then reverting back to ntfs, i just formatted the hard drive to ext4 which didnt fix the issue initially but then went into terminal did chown terry /mnt/game which seems to have fixed the issue. after formatting the drive to ext4. it seems my installation of ubuntu seems to prefer ext4 over ntfs

Answer (score 0):

You might need to reformat your hard disk.

1. Go into “Disks”
2. Select your 4TB hard drive.
3. Press the “Format Disk” button (not just the partition).
4. Make sure your select GPT and Erase data, then wait for the format to complete.

5 (Optional). Check in on your S.M.A.R.T. data, and make sure you don’t have a ton of bad sectors (mine has 3039, and that’s really bad because I can’t even store LibreOffice files on it)

6. Format the partition as Ext4 or NTFS
7. Done! Please let me know if this worked!